Firestore Admin SDK always gives "No QuerySnapshot Result" error
When doing a database query for my Firebase collection, it always gives me a "No QuerySnapshot Result" error, even if there are documents matching the query.
try {
  const diaryReference = firestore.collection("diary");
  const userEntriesSnapshot = await diaryReference
    .where("userID", "==", user.id)
    .where("time", ">=", startOfDayTimestamp)
    .where("time", "<=", endOfDayTimestamp)
    .get();

  if (userEntriesSnapshot.empty) {
    usersToNotify.push(user.fcmToken);
  } else {
    console.log(`✅ Found entries for ${user.id} today.`);
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log("❌ Firebase Query Snapshot Error", error);
  console.log(user.fcmToken);
  usersToNotify.push(user.fcmToken);
}

Error 774 |      *  transaction, or timestamp to use as read time.
775 |      */
776 |     async _get(transactionOrReadTime) {
777 |         const result = await this._getResponse(transactionOrReadTime);
778 |         if (!result.result) {
779 |             throw new Error('No QuerySnapshot result');
                        ^
error: No QuerySnapshot result
      at /Users/rohanrocks/VSCode/InsightfullApi/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference/query.js:779:19


What is this._getResponse, and what exactly are you expecting it to return?  Please edit the question to include all relevant code. We should be able to copy what you have and duplicate the result.

this._getResponse is part of the error, I don't know where that code came from.

I'm still getting this error after multiple chatgpt requests, has anybody else encountered this before?

You still haven't shown us what this._getResponse is.  We can't help you if you don't do some debugging and figure out what's behind that.

this._getResponse is part of the code in the @google-cloud/firestore package, I can't change any of that code
